Why calling representations that way? What do they represent?
Beeing a student of mathematics, in particular interested in algebra and representation theory, i am not only interested in the rigid axioms and definition but also in the intuition and the names behind it.
I know the definitions of representations, roughly speaken its a homomorphism from your object into the endomorphisms of a vectorspace, but as much as i see it, it rather describes an action on a vector space.
For example a rep. of a group G is a group homomorphism $\rho:G \to Gl_F(V):= \{A:V \to V | A \text{ is an isomorphism} \}$ (while $V$ is a $F$-vector space). This gives you a multiplication $\cdot:G \times V \to V$ by $gv := \rho(g)(v)$ that respects the vector space structures (via linearity). And i would tend to call it a $G$-Module rather than a representation (like its done with "representations" of rings) because i think this name would fit a lot better.
I dont see why the vector space with this multiplication "represents" the group. But as much as i know understanding the representations of a group is used to understand the group. So i guess in some sort of way the representation(s) of a group do represent it. Is there a connection to "the idea" of groups? As symmetries acting on something?
This is some knot in my head i couldn't fix yet, i would be glad to here an answer on this topic: Why is a (group) representation called that, what is the (likely) intuition behind it, that makes us call it that way instead of module?
Thanks a lot!

It literally represents your group elements as matrices.

It affords a way to think of group elements as linear transformations; i.e., it allows you to represent group elements as linear transformations.

In some sense, at least a faithful representation is an isomorphism to a subgroup of $GL(V)$ for some vector space $V.$ More generally, it is just a homomorphism, but the set of representations is a way to get the kinds of geometric symmetry that a group represents.

There are lots of other kinds of representations, but the main ones which has been used in group theory is as functions on vector spaces. In particular, there are lots of useful rules about decomposition of representations, a kind of unique factorization of linear representations.

@Randall so i assume this is nothing aelse than the equivalent of seeing finite groups as permutation groups (on some sort of 'wider area')

@TimonKolt pretty much, that's how it all started.

Yes, the most basic representation is as symmetry groups. The more general idea of representations is in category theory, as functors. Symmetry group representations of  groups are functors to the category of sets. Linear representations are functors to categories of vector spaces.

You should read the wikipedia entry for representations (mathematics). It gives several examples of representations of mathematic objects outside of group theory.

Many answers in the comments. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See here for more information. https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19756/how-do-comments-work

For example, the Statue of Liberty represents the liberty: it gives a concrete shape to an abstract concept/principle.

Please do not answer questions in the comments. I feel like at least two comments here could be answers.

@Shaun Is it a good idea to collect these comments and answer&accept my own question, to show the algorithm this question is answered&accepted?

If you put things into your own words and give people credit, then yes, @TimonKolt.  Click the time stamp next to the comment to be directed to a version of the page with said comment highlighted. Then you can use that URL to link to it in your answer.

@anomaly This is an answer to the question, not just a comment. Comments should only be used to clarify, not answer the question. See How do comments work for more information. Therefore, please post your answer as an answer.

Collecting the helpful comments above to a complete answer:
Given a group $G$ and a vector space $V$, a homomorphism $\rho:G \to Gl(V)$ allows us to view the group as a group of matrices, so from that point of view the name "representation" is somehow intuitiv and "makes sense" (according to
@Randall Why calling representations that way? What do they represent?, to be more precise as linear transformations a.c. @ArturoMagidin Why calling representations that way? What do they represent?).
This starts to become totally clear/obvious when your representation is faithful, meaning that $\rho$ is injective and hence an isomorphism to a subgroup of automorphisms over $V$, or in finite dimensional case: to a group of matrices. At this point you can totally forget your original group $G$ and rather work with a group of linear transformations which tends to be more intuitive, because they are so well understood. This is a pretty similar approach to what is done in linear algebra, where "abstract linear transformations" are represented by matrices, because they are better to understand and can be approached more easily, in particular, for new/undergraduate students or non-mathematicians.
It also allows us to return to a geometric/symmetrical view on our group, as we can not only examine the group structure, but also view the group as symmetries/transformations acting on a vector space. So we can understand a hidden geometric impact/effect that the group has, for example by viewing it as  orthogonal matrices/transformations instead of viewing it as permutations. Which kind of is a funny example because seeing a group as a permutation group is a similar approach, and allows us to see the group elements as symmetries ~a invariant transformations, acting on something. As an example you can view the  group $(\mathbb Z / 3\mathbb Z,+)$ as a permutation  sub-group of $S_3$, i.e. as symmetries acting on an equilateral triangle (or a set of three points). Sometimes this $G$-sets $( \text{a homomorphism } p:(G,\cdot) \to (\{f:M\to M | f \text{ bijection }\},\circ) $ for a set $M)$ are also called representations.
This thoughts were mainly induced by @ThomasAndrews Why calling representations that way? What do they represent?.
So, concluding all this information, one can say: A representation allows us to view/represent your group as symmetries/transformations and make it easier/more intuitive to understand. The wider approach (than an isomorphism) gives you the opportunity you focus on certain aspects of your group, or gives a wider area of accesses to represent (parts) of your group with different tools (e.g. matrices), than a rigid iromorphism. And last but not least it can give you information about the group in its totality (like geometry, group as symmetries acting on something...), which are usually hard to examine if you only look at the group with its inner structure $(G,\cdot)$, by representing it as transformations.

As for $G$-modules, you certainly can talk about the action of a group $G$ on modules; a classical representation is effectively a $\mathbb{C}[G]$-module. The general case is very useful (e.g., the common setup of Galois groups acting on modules in arithmetic geometry, or the classification of group extensions by group cohomology), but the situation is broader and more complicated, for the same reason that the study of modules is broader and more complicated than that of vector spaces. For a concrete example, compare the thorny case of modular representation theory (i.e., $k[G]$-modules for $\text{char} \; k | \#G$) to the classical case of representations over $\mathbb{C}$.
But more specifically to the question: A representation of a group really is just an action on a vector space (by homomorphisms, which are necessarily isomorphisms). Vector space isomorphisms are very well understood, which makes this tactic useful. For a specific nontrivial example of what representation theory can do, take a look at the proof of Burnside's theorem. (Not the lemma, but the one that says that any finite group of order $p^n q^m$ for primes $p,q$ is solvable.)
